# How to convert H2Database database file to MySQL database .sql file?

Tags: mysql, h2

I have some data in [H2Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) file and I want to convert it to MySQL `.sql` database file. What are the methods I can follow?

Answer (score 9):

In answer to Thomas Mueller, SquirrelSQL worked fine for me.
Here is the procedure for Windows to convert a H2 database:

1. Go to "drivers list", where everything is red by default.
2. Select "H2" driver, and specify the full path to "h2-1.3.173.jar" (for
       example) in "Extra Class Path". The H2 driver should display a blue
       check in the list.
3. Select your target driver (PostgreSQL, MySQL), and
       do the same, for example for PostgreSQL, specify the full path to
       "postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar" in Extra Class Path.
4. Go to "Aliases", then click on "+" for H2 : configure your JDBC chain, for example copy/paste the jdbc chain you obtain when you launch H2, and do the same for your target database: click on "+", configure and "test".
5. When you double click on your alias, you should see everything inside your database in a new Tab. Go to the tables in source database, do a multi-select on all your tables and do a right-click : "Copy Table".
6. Go to your target database from Alias, and do a "Paste Table". When all tables are copied altogether, the foreign key references are also generated.
7. Check your primary keys : from H2 to PostgreSQL, I lost the Primary Key constraints, and the auto-increment capability. 
   You could also rename columns and tables by a right click : "refactor". I used it to rename reserved words columns after full copy, by disabling name check in options.

   This worked well for me.

Comment: Hey @Elo, im trying to do this what you explained and i'm getting this error: Error: ERROR: column "content" is of type oid but expression is of type bytea. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry @user14073111, couldn't help : I didn't have this problem and I don't work anymore with these databases.

Comment: If you're wondering where to disable column name check in SQuirrel settings, go to File -> Global Preferences -> DB Copy Tab -> Scroll down to Column Type Mappings Group and uncheck "Check column names in copied tables for keywords in destination database" and "Test column names in copied tables to see if they are valid for the destination table"
It took me a while to find it, so I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

The SQL script generated by the H2 database is not fully compatible with the SQL supported by MySQL. You would have to change the SQL script manually. This requires that you know both H2 and MySQL quite well.

To avoid this problem, an alternative, probably simpler way to copy the data from H2 to MySQL is to use a 3rd party tool such as the [SQuirreL SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) together with the [SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin](http://dbcopyplugin.sourceforge.net/) plugin. (First you need to install SQuirreL SQL and on top of that the SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin.)

Comment: I used SQuirreL SQL together with the SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin plugin. But it does no work it gives

Copy failed: No database selected(SQL Erro Code=1046)

Failed SQL was:
CREARE TABLE .....
....
...
..

(No bind variables)


How to fix this.

Comment: Well, I guess you should ask at the SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin mailing list. But I wonder, if the error message is "No database select" - did you select a database?

Comment: In the top left corner, there is a drop down called "Catalog", there select the database to which you want to copy the tables. 

This issue might have been solved, but I hit the same issue today and adding this comment for someone else having the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I created a Groovy script that does the migration from h2 to mysql. From there you could do a mysqldump. It requires that the tables exists in the Mysql database. It should work for ohter DBMS with minor changes.

```
@Grapes(
[ 
    @Grab(group='mysql', module='mysql-connector-java', version='5.1.26'),
    @Grab(group='com.h2database', module='h2', version='1.3.166'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
])

import groovy.sql.Sql

def h2Url='jdbc:h2:C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\h2\\sonardata\\sonar'
def h2User='sonar'
def h2Passwd='sonar'

def mysqlUrl='jdbc:mysql://10.56.xxx.xxx:3306/sonar?useunicode=true&characterencoding=utf8&rewritebatchedstatements=true'
def mysqlUser='sonar'
def mysqlPasswd='xxxxxx'
def mysqlDatabase='sonar'


sql = Sql.newInstance(h2Url, h2User, h2Passwd, 'org.h2.Driver' )

def tables = [:]

sql.eachRow("select * from information_schema.columns where table_schema='PUBLIC'") {
    if(!it.TABLE_NAME.endsWith("_MY")) {
        if (tables[it.TABLE_NAME] == null) {
            tables[it.TABLE_NAME] = []
        }
        tables[it.TABLE_NAME] += it.COLUMN_NAME;
    }
}

tables.each{tab, cols ->
    println("processing $tab")
    println("droppin $tab"+"_my")

    sql.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tab+"_my;")
    sql.execute("create linked table "+tab+"_my ('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', '"+mysqlUrl+"', '"+mysqlUser+"', '"+mysqlPasswd+"', '"+mysqlDatabase+"."+tab.toLowerCase()+"');")

    sql.eachRow("select count(*) as c from " + tab + "_my"){println("deleting $it.c entries from mysql table")}
    result = sql.execute("delete from "+tab+"_my")
    colString = cols.join(", ")
    sql.eachRow("select count(*) as c from " + tab){println("starting to copy $it.c entries")}
    sql.execute("insert into " + tab + "_my ("+colString+") select "+colString+" from " + tab)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The H2 database allows you to create a SQL script using the [`SCRIPT`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script) SQL statement or the [Script command line tool](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Script.html). Possibly you will need to tweak the script before you can run it against the MySQL database.

Comment: I tried to do it. But it fails. Can you give me an example script to to it

Comment: As I wrote, you may have to modify the script before you can run it against MySQL.

Comment: What are the modification i have to do ? always im getting error. Im using mysql 5.1.61.

Comment: MySQL and H2 are not fully compatible. What modifications you need to do exactly depends on the SQL script.

Comment: I have added another answer: to use the "SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin" instead of the script feature of H2. See below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fullconvert to convert database. it's easy to use.

Follow steps shown here

https://www.fullconvert.com/howto/h2-to-mysql

Comment: This tool costs $699; the trial edition deliberately mangles data